# Spring Security JWT Example without spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-security, jwt

I have a Spring 5 MVC/REST application. i using JPA Hibernate as the ORM.
I want to secure my application. All examples I see are based on Spring Boot.
I want use jwt in my application. I want without XML Config too.

( **Spring MVC - 5.2.0.RELEASE** )

I need Example. Thanks

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ?: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt

Comment: thanks dear @R.G but I want example without Spring boot

Comment: @mohammad_soleimani did u manage to find the solution without spring boot.

Comment: dear @oOXAam , there is a example in GitHub now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write a sample for use Spring security 5.0.0 none boot and with JWT, dynamic Role.
I hope it's good

1. Spring MVC 5.0.0
2. Spring Security 5.0.0
3. hibernate JPA 5.2.11
4. and my DB is Oracle DB

you can download it :
[download from github](https://github.com/mamadsolimani/Spring-Security-5-JWT-none-boot)

Answer (score 2):

To secure a Spring REST application using Spring Security and JWT, you can follow the below steps

1. Add the following dependencies in pom.xml

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
       <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
       <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
       <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
       <version>0.9.1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Create JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint to rejet every unauthenticated request

   ```
   @Component
   public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {
   @Override
   public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
       response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
   }
   }
   ```
3. Create model classes

   ```
   public class JwtRequest implements Serializable {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 5926468583005150707L;
       private String username;
       private String password;

       // need default constructor for JSON Parsing
       public JwtRequest() {
       }

       public JwtRequest(String username, String password) {
           this.setUsername(username);
           this.setPassword(password);
       }
   // Getters and Setters
   }

   public class JwtResponse implements Serializable {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = -8091879091924046844L;
       private final String jwttoken;

       public JwtResponse(String jwttoken) {
           this.jwttoken = jwttoken;
       }

       public String getToken() {
           return this.jwttoken;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create Util class for token generation and validation

   ```
   @Component
   public class JwtTokenUtil implements Serializable {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = -2550185165626007488L;
       public static final long JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY = 5 * 60 * 60;
       @Value("${jwt.secret}")
       private String secret;

       // retrieve username from jwt token
       public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
           return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject);
       }

       // retrieve expiration date from jwt token
       public Date getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
           return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getExpiration);
       }

       public <T> T getClaimFromToken(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
           final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
           return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
       }

       // for retrieveing any information from token we will need the secret key
       private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
           return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
       }

       // check if the token has expired
       private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
           final Date expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token);
           return expiration.before(new Date());
       }

       // generate token for user
       public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
           Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
           return doGenerateToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
       }

       // while creating the token -
       // 1. Define claims of the token, like Issuer, Expiration, Subject, and the ID
       // 2. Sign the JWT using the HS512 algorithm and secret key.
       // 3. According to JWS Compact
       // Serialization(https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature-41#section-3.1)
       // compaction of the JWT to a URL-safe string
       private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
           return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                   .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY * 1000)).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret).compact();
       }

       // validate token
       public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
           final String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
           return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
       }
   }
   ```
5. Create UserDetailsService and UserRepository implementations to load the user by user name from database

   ```
   @Service
   public class JwtUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

       @Autowired
       private UserRepository repo;

       @Override
       public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
           UserEntity user = repo.findByUsername(username);
           if (user != null) {
               return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());
           } else {
               throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. Create a reqeust filter to check if the request has a valid JWT token. If it has a valid JWT Token then set the Authentication in the context, to specify that the current user is authenticated.

   ```
   @Component
   public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
   @Autowired
   private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;
   @Autowired
   private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

   @Override
   protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
       final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
       String username = null;
       String jwtToken = null;
       // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get
       // only the Token
       if (requestTokenHeader != null &amp;&amp; requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
           jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
           try {
               username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
           } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
               System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
           } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
               System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
           }
       } else {
           logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
       }
       // Once we get the token validate it.
       if (username != null &amp;&amp; SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
           UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
           // if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set
           // authentication
           if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
               UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
               usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
               // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
               // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the
               // Spring Security Configurations successfully.
               SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
           }
       }
       chain.doFilter(request, response);
   }
   }
   ```
7. Create an authentication controller to expose a POST API **/authenticate** which accepts username and password in the body. Using Spring Authentication Manager we authenticate the username and password. If the credentials are valid, a JWT token is created using the JwtTokenUtil and provided to the client.

   ```
       @RestController
       @CrossOrigin
       public class JwtAuthenticationController {
       @Autowired
       private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
       @Autowired
       private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
       @Autowired
       private JwtUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

       @PostMapping("/authenticate")
       public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {
           authenticate(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());
           final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
           final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
           return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));
       }

       private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
           try {
               authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
           } catch (DisabledException e) {
               throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED", e);
           } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
               throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", e);
           }
       }
       }
   ```
8. Configure Spring Security

   ```
   @Configuration
   @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.javachinna")
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   @Autowired
   private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
   @Autowired
   private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;
   @Autowired
   private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

   @Autowired
   public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
       // user for matching credentials
       // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
       auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
   }

   @Bean
   public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
       return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
   }

   @Bean
   @Override
   public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
       return super.authenticationManagerBean();
   }

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
       // We don't need CSRF for this example
       httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
               // dont authenticate this particular request
               .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().
               // all other requests need to be authenticated
               anyRequest().authenticated().and().
               // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
               // store user's state.
               exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
       // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
       httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
   }
   }
   ```
9. Create SecurityWebApplicationInitializer to register the springSecurityFilterChain

   ```
   public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

   }
   ```
10. Add the WebSecurityConfig class to the existing ApplicationInitializer

    ```
    public class SpringWebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebSecurityConfig.class };
    }
    // ... other overrides ...
    }
    ```
11. Add the secret key to the application.properties file

    ### App Properties

    jwt.secret=javachinna

That's it. Now generate a JSON Web Token by creating a POST request with url localhost:8080/authenticate and valid username and password in the request body. Use this token in the request header for each request.

For more information, refer the [article on Securing Spring REST services using JWT without using spring boot](https://www.javachinna.com/2020/02/01/securing-spring-rest-services-using-jwt-without-using-spring-boot/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25240896)

Comment: I've included the essential parts of the answer here and provided the link for reference.